# Run code when a push notification is received. Even when the app is in background

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are facing a huge problem with our React Native mobile app.
Right now we implemented all the Firebase SDK for iOS and Android, and is working pretty well.

Our main need is to perform some fast background tasks when a notification (from our servers) hits a device. We could not find any way to achieve this properly.
On android at least we have the option to create a background service, but will be only an middle-way solution, because the tasks will be not performed in real time.

Anyone have a solution to run a React Native (Javascript) code even when the app is in background? Are welcome solutions only for a single operating system too (iOS or Android)

Thanks in advance!

P.S: It's pretty

Comment: I had the same problem, couldn't find a solution to this 6 months ago.

Comment: It's just not possible to run JS code in the background, the JS runtime isn't available

Comment: @dentemm What about with a native module?

Comment: You can indeed use native code to perform tasks, but the JS side of the native module will only get called once the app re-enters the foreground. I am using this technique myself.

Comment: I actually checked the source code for native modules (on iOS at least), and when your app is in the background and the native code performs tasks they get queued . As soon as the app enters the foreground, the entire task queue is sent over to the JS side at once.